# How to use split method for finding average of two specific columns of doubles of a .txt

Tags: java, arrays, split

I need to read the lines of this .txt file/store them into an array while ignoring the T's, use only the numbers from the columns of `MaxT` and `MinT` in this text and to find the average on `MaxT` and `MinT` then print them onto a label for a GUI. I'm currently stuck after reading the lines and spliting them by the tabs they are separated by.

```
Day MaxT    MinT    AvgT    Dept    HDD CDD Prep    NewSnow
1   61  38  49.5    17.8    15  0   0.00    0.0
2   60  33  46.5    14.7    18  0   0.93    0.0
3   60  36  48.0    16.0    17  0   0.80    0.0
4   36  22  29.0    -3.1    36  0   T   T
5   43  18  30.5    -1.8    34  0   0.00    0.0
6   47  22  34.5    2.1 30  0   0.00    0.0
7   53  31  42.0    9.4 23  0   0.00    0.0
8   45  23  34.0    1.2 31  0   0.27    2.1
9   24  15  19.5    -13.5   45  0   0.14    2.0
10  18  11  14.5    -18.7   50  0   0.03    0.7
11  25  11  18.0    -15.4   47  0   T   T
12  28  18  23.0    -10.6   42  0   0.01    0.2
13  19  10  14.5    -19.3   50  0   T   T
14  21  11  16.0    -18.1   49  0   0.17    2.9
15  36  21  28.5    -5.8    36  0   T   0.0
16  38  25  31.5    -3.1    33  0   0.02    0.0
17  36  26  31.0    -3.8    34  0   T   T
18  44  27  35.5    0.4 29  0   0.00    0.0
19  66  39  52.5    17.1    12  0   0.00    0.0
20  72  49  60.5    24.9    4   0   0.00    0.0
21  59  41  50.0    14.1    15  0   1.57    0.0
22  50  33  41.5    5.3 23  0   0.00    0.0
23  56  32  44.0    7.5 21  0   0.02    0.0
24  61  33  47.0    10.2    18  0   1.03    T
25  37  32  34.5    -2.6    30  0   0.04    0.5
26  38  31  34.5    -2.9    30  0   T   T
27  52  27  39.5    1.7 25  0   0.00    0.0
28  66  42  54.0    15.9    11  0   T   0.0
29  60  38  49.0    10.8    16  0   0.21    0.0




try{
     File inputFile = new File("climateDataCincinnati.txt"); //get text 
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile); //scanner for text
                    String line = "";
                    in.nextLine(); //to consume the first row
                    while(in.hasNextLine()){ //while there is a next line do
                        line = in.nextLine(); //take line
                        String content[] = line.split("\t"); // split by tabs
//where to seperate the two columns from the others 
                }
                catch (IOException exception){
                    System.out.println(exception.toString());
                }
```

Comment: how about white space ?

Comment: `MaxT` is index 1 and `MinT` is index 2 when splitting each line. Once you get those parsed out, it should be easy to get an average from a list of numbers.

Comment: So how exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store the columns you need in lists. You may as well parse the string to Integer as you iterate through the values.

```
List<Integer> maxList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> minList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(in.hasNextLine()){ //while there is a next line do
   line = in.nextLine(); //take line
   String content[] = line.split("\t"); // split by tabs
   //get the maxT and minT
   Integer maxT = Integer.valueOf(content[1]);
   Integer minT = Integer.valueOf(content[2]);
   //store for future use
   maxList.add(maxT); 
   minList.add(minT);
   }

//Do something on your 2 lists to find the average
```